# error when checking if string in array is null

Tags: c++, string, pointers, struct, hashtable

I'm setting up a hash table, and I've computed the key, and want to determine if that spot in the array already has something in it or not. I figured I should check if its null to see if the space is empty or if it has been deleted. The `del.compare` is to check if the first name string has been replaced by `"DEL"`, which is how I mark the elements that have been deleted and ready to be rewritten.

I'm getting an error:

`error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘(((Student*)this)->Student::studentList + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)((Student*)this)->Student::key) * 20u)))->Student::studentEntry::FIRST != 0’`

For this line:

`if(studentList[key].FIRST != NULL || del.compare(studentList[key].FIRST) != 0)`

What's wrong with using `!=` in this instance?

edit about `del.compare`:

I'm just using the string library compare, in this case `del` is initialized in the function:

`string del("DEL");`

and `studentList[key].FIRST` corresponds to a pointer to a struct of strings, initialized to `10`.  `studentList[0].FIRST` should be the first name of the first entry in the array of `10`, and it should be empty.

Here's how I declared it in a constructor:

`studentList = new studentEntry[10];`

edit about `FIRST`:

`FIRST` is declared in the `Students` class inside the `studentEntry` struct.  That part looks like:

```
class Student
{
    private:    
        struct studentEntry
        {
            string FIRST; 
        };
        studentEntry *studentList;
        int key;
        int index;

    public:
        void add(string &firstname);
        Student();
};
```

This is the constructor for the `Student` class, which might also be relevant:

```
Student::Student()
{
    studentList = new studentEntry[10];
    key = 0;
    index = 0;  
}
```

edit about `add`:

Here is the `add` function where the compare is made that is causing the error:

```
void Student::add(string &firstname)
{       
    string del("DEL");

    //find key to know which bucket to use
    key = index % 10;

    //check if spot in studentList is empty or has been removed
    if(studentList[key].FIRST != NULL || del.compare(studentList[key].FIRST) != 0)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>the compiler says that the result of `del.compare` is not comparable to 0</del>

<del>you have not shown anything about `del.compare`, so more cannot be said</del>

at the moment lacking a declaration of `FIRST`…

---

Sometime later – `FIRST` is now revealed to be a `string`, presumably a `std::string`.

You can't compare a `std::string` to 0 or to a `nullptr`.

But you can compare its `length()` to 0, for example.

Comment: I updated the question, sorry, I thought the problem was with the first half of the `||`

Comment: @manalishi: apparently my answer was wrong then. please show a complete small example program.

Comment: Okay, I added more info on `FIRST` as well as the class and constructor I used

Comment: thanks, thats what it was.  Changed it to `studentList[key].FIRST.length() != 0`